# Steam OpenID 403 forbidden

Tags: openid, steam

I have a Steam OpenID to login on my website from 2 years and yesterday I have a blockade because php return 403 error.

[screenshot of get_headers("https://steamcommunity.com/openid")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXxDv.png)

I didn't change anything (the code or something), I didn't abuse it (I have an excerpt from the logos implemented on the site and I know who logged in) so I know why I have 403 error.

Is there anyone who would be able to help me? Why was the blockade imposed, or to whom to write to reverse it?

**Code**

```
<?php
class SteamSignIn {
    const STEAM_LOGIN = 'https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login';
    public static function genUrl($returnTo = false, $useAmp = true) {
        $returnTo = (!$returnTo) ? (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http').'://agromex.wooqash.net/' : $returnTo;
        $params = array(
            'openid.ns' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
            'openid.mode' => 'checkid_setup',
            'openid.return_to' => $returnTo,
            'openid.realm' => (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http').'://agromex.wooqash.net/',
            'openid.identity' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
            'openid.claimed_id' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
        );
        $sep = ($useAmp) ? '&amp;' : '&';
        return self::STEAM_LOGIN . '?' . http_build_query($params, '', $sep);
    }
    public static function validate() {
        $params = array(
            'openid.assoc_handle' => $_GET['openid_assoc_handle'],
            'openid.signed' => $_GET['openid_signed'],
            'openid.sig' => $_GET['openid_sig'],
            'openid.ns' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
        );
        $signed = explode(',', $_GET['openid_signed']);
        foreach($signed as $item)
        {
            $val = $_GET['openid_' . str_replace('.', '_', $item)];
            $params['openid.' . $item] = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($val) : $val; 
        }
        $params['openid.mode'] = 'check_authentication';
        $data =  http_build_query($params);
        $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => 
                    "Accept-language: en\r\n".
                    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                    "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
                'content' => $data,
            ),
        ));
        $result = file_get_contents(self::STEAM_LOGIN, false, $context);
        preg_match("#^https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/([0-9]{17,25})#", $_GET['openid_claimed_id'], $matches);
        $steamID64 = is_numeric($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : 0;
        return preg_match("#is_valid\s*:\s*true#i", $result) == 1 ? $steamID64 : '';
    }
}
print_r(get_headers("https://steamcommunity.com/openid"));
$steamapi = SteamSignIn::validate();
echo "<hr />";
print_r($steamapi);
```

?>

**Result**

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden [1] => Server: AkamaiGHost [2] => Mime-Version: 1.0 [3] => Content-Type: text/html [4] => Content-Length: 269 [5] => Expires: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:33:56 GMT [6] => Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:33:56 GMT [7] => Connection: close)
```

Comment: Posting the code will help others solve this issue, without seeing your code, chances are no one an help/

Comment: I added the code in main post.